# How do I fill a text box using a public string?

Tags: c#

I have this frustrating problem that I can't seem to solve.

I try to fill a `TextBox` with text from a public static string.
But when I run the program it just shows a blank text box with nothing in it.

I don't have any errors so it's hard for me to understand what I'm doing wrong.

Here is the code I have:

```
public ShowMp3()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    OverzichttxtBox.Text = OverzichtMP3();
}

public static String OverzichtMP3()
{
    String overzicht = "";

    foreach (Mp3Player player in Mp3.GetPlayers())
        overzicht = overzicht + "ID: " + Convert.ToString(player.id) + "\r\n" +
                    "Merk: " + player.make + "\r\n" + "Model: " + player.model +
                    "\r\n" + "MB-size: " + player.mBSize + "\r\n" + "Prijs: " +
                    player.price + "\r\n" + "\r\n";

    return overzicht;
}
```

And `Mp3.GetPlayers()` is this:

```
private static ArrayList players = new ArrayList();

public static void Initialize()
{
    Mp3Player player1 = new Mp3Player(1, "GET Technologies .inc", "HF 410", 4096, 129.95M, 500);
    Mp3Player player2 = new Mp3Player(2, "Far & Loud", "XM 600", 8192, 224.95M, 500);
    Mp3Player player3 = new Mp3Player(3, "Innotivative ", "Z3", 512, 79.95M, 500);
    Mp3Player player4 = new Mp3Player(4, "Resistance S.A.", "3001", 4096, 124.95M, 500);
    Mp3Player player5 = new Mp3Player(5, "CBA", "NXT Volume", 2048, 159.05M, 500);

    players.Add(player1);
    players.Add(player2);
    players.Add(player3);
    players.Add(player4);
    players.Add(player5);
}

public static ArrayList GetPlayers()
{
    return players;
}
```

Comment: Show how you call into this code.

Comment: do you have any items returned from Mp3.GetPLayers()?

Comment: Though, `overzicht = overzicht = ` can't be right.

Comment: Do you ever call `Initialize()`?

Comment: I'd rather use a StringBuilder it is mutable. Concatenating strings is not very efficient, especially if your Mp3.GetPlayers list gets too large. Use the Append method to concatenate..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect the problem is you're never calling `Mp3.Initialize()`.  You could add this to a static constructor in the `Mp3` class:

```
private static List<Mp3Player> players = new List<Mp3Player>();

static Mp3() 
{
    Initialize();
}

// This can be private now...
private static void Initialize()
{
     ....
```

Note that you may want to change the `ArrayList` to a `List<Mp3Player>`, as well.

Answer (score 1):

Also, as an aside, you should give `StringBuilder` and `String.Format` a try. Instead of this...

```
overzicht = overzicht + "ID: " + Convert.ToString(player.id) + "\r\n" +
            "Merk: " + player.make + "\r\n" + "Model: " + player.model +
            "\r\n" + "MB-size: " + player.mBSize + "\r\n" + "Prijs: " +
            player.price + "\r\n" + "\r\n";
```

You can do:

```
StringBuilder overzicht = new StringBuilder();

overzicht.AppendLine(String.Format("ID: {0}", player.id));
overzicht.AppendLine(String.Format("Merk: {0}", player.make));
overzicht.AppendLine(String.Format("Model: {0}", player.model));
overzicht.AppendLine(String.Format("MB-size: {0}", player.mBSize));
overzicht.AppendLine(String.Format("Prijs: {0}", player.price));

return overzicht.ToString();
```

Much easier to read ;)

My String.Format isn't that compelling here... but if this was all on one line, it'd be much more useful:

```
return String.Format("ID:{0}, Merk:{1}, Model:{2}, MB-size:{3}, Prijs:{4}",
                     player.id, player.make, player.mode, 
                     player.mBSize, player.price);
```

Comment: Another option: `String.Format("ID: {1}{0}Merk:{2}{0}Model:{3}{0}MB-size:{4}{0}Prijs:{5}", Environment.NewLine, player.id, player.make, player.mode, player.mBSize, player.price);` though arguably less readable...

Comment: Yea, I had thought about that but decided against posting it because of the readability factor. Thanks for the input ;)